# Backbone correct way to extend Backbone.Model

Tags: backbone.js, marionette

I am trying to use RESTful api to signup a user.

Here is my model code:

```
var User = Backbone.Model.extend({
    idAttribute: '_id',
    host: 'http://localhost:3000',
    url: '/api/user'
});
```

This is the code in my view for handling signup button click:

```
signupClick: function (e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    var email = $('#input-email').val();
    var pwd1 = $('#input-pwd').val();
    var pwd2 = $('#input-pwd2').val();

    if(pwd1 !== pwd2) {
        return alert('password does not equal');
    }

    var user = new UserModel({email: email, password: pwd1});
    user.sync();

}
```

The API is on localhost: 
POST /api/user 
Body: {email:'email@email.com', password:'123456'}

But I got the following error msg in browser console:

> Uncaught Error: A "url" property or function must be specified

What did I do wrong in this model?  Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

By default, models generate a url by deferring to their containing collection's "url()" function. If you have a model which is not managed by a collection, you should specify the model's "urlRoot" property.

So, in your example, change your model to this and you should get what you're after:

```
var User = Backbone.Model.extend({
    idAttribute: '_id',
    host: 'http://localhost:3000',
    urlRoot: '/api/user'
});
```

[ relevant documentation is here: http://backbonejs.org/#Model-url ]

Comment: I just tried your code. It is still not working, same error msg.

Comment: I also read the document that you suggested, it is a bit confusing to me, because I still don't understand how to specify the url for model without collection. Please help.

Comment: Sorry, I didn't notice you were also calling user.sync(), rather than user.save(). You want to use the latter. Also, in your example you defined the model as User, but then instantiated an instance of UserModel. Guessing that was just a typo, as you'd get a different error if that issue was in your real code.